# Imagecopy not working properly

Tags: php, get, png, gd

I have been trying to implement a rating display procedure to rating in form of stars as passed by GET in a php file.

Here's the code for rate.php :

```
$filename= "rating.png";
$rating = $_GET['rating'];
list($w, $h, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
$src_im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$dst_im = imagecreatefrompng("rating_back.png");
$src_x = '0';   // begin x
$src_y = '0';   // begin y
$src_w = $w * $rating / 5; // width
$src_h = $h; // height
$dst_x = '0';   // destination x
$dst_y = '0';   // destination y
imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($dst_im);
imagedestroy($dst_im);
```

`$rating` is a float value as per the GET request.
But when I try to implement `rate.php?rating=4.3` using the following images:

"rating.png":

[image: rating.png]

"rating_back.png":

[image: rating_back.png]

I get the following result :

[image]

What could be the possible errors which are leading to an abnormal background in the final image?

Please give the possible solutions also.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like those are 24 bit PNG images with transparency. You need to tell GD to save the transparency info too. Add:

```
imagesavealpha($dst_im, true);
```

before rendering your image

Comment: I did it before imagecopy();

Comment: And... It works ! :)
But could you tell me why imagecopy() doesn't work alone?
Both the images have the same transparent region, then why does that happen?

Comment: `imagecopy` does what it's supposed to do, but GD will not preserve alpha values by default when saving. Why did GD authors chose this behavior? That I don't know